# Geoserver WMS layer is hiding the basemap in a Leaflet map

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms

When I add two layers to a Leaflet map (a basemap and a Geoserver WMS), the basemap disappers. But when its tiling, it can be seen for a moment.

What's the problem? Maybe it's due to the transparency or to the zIndex?

This is the basemap (OSM)

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        zIndex: 2
    }).addTo(map);
```

and this is the Geoserver WMS

```
var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://188.213.174.15:8080/geoserver/wms?', {
    layers: 'varymaps:badacstur',
    transparent: true,
    zIndex: 1
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving a zIndex to the basemap with a superior value than the WMS layer, my guess is that's what causing this problem, you should invert the z-indexes

basemap : `zIndex: 1;`

WMS layer: `zIndex: 2;`

Answer (score 1):

If you're not specifying a [`format` option in your `L.TileLayer.WMS`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#tilelayer-wms-format), the default of JPEG format is used - a image format that does not support transparency.

Comment: I used
  format: 'image/png',
  transparent: true,